# i have problem with pass variables through all php files

Tags: php, twilio

Hello i created simple project with twilio api it call users and say his/her name and username so user need verify account by press digits he see in register page same us aws amazon but i have problem look this is how i use session

```html
<html><head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="uzDIA.css">
</head>
<body><div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="jes.php" method="POST">
    <h3></h3>
    <h4></h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="name" name="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required="" autofocus="">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="name" name="username" type="text" tabindex="2" required="">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Number" name="phone" type="tel" tabindex="3" required="">

 </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">submit </button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

</body></html>
```

i need to pass this variables through all php files that i have i used session did not work i use include did not work i use get method did not work when i press submit no variables share

#### my action page

```
     <?php
  session_start();
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

  $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
  $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['phone']=$_POST['[phone'];

  header("location : /1-outbound-call.php");

}


?>
```

#### 1-outbound-call.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';
include 'config.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$number=$_SESSION['phone'];

$account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$auth_token = 'xxxxxxx';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
// A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
$twilio_number = "+4474xxxxx";
$url="http://example.com/2-call-answered.php";
// Where to make a voice call (your cell phone?)

$to_number = $phone;

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->account->calls->create(  
    $to_number,
    $twilio_number,
    array(
        "url" => "$url",
    )
);
?>
```

#### 2-call-answered.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// Create a route that will handle Twilio webhook requests, sent as an
// HTTP POST to /voice in our application
require_once 'Twilio/autoload.php';
include 'config.php';
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$user=$_SESSION['username'];

use Twilio\Twiml;
// Use the Twilio PHP SDK to build an XML response
$response = new Twiml();
// Use the <Gather> verb to collect user input
$gather = $response->gather(array('numDigits' => 6, 'action' => '/3-gather.php?'));
$url="2-call-answered.php";

// use the <Say> verb to request input from the user
$gather->say("hello $name your username is $username please confirm blah blah blah  ");

// If the user doesn't enter input, loop
$response->redirect($url);

// Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Session variables are the correct way.

Comment: @Barmar i used it but did not work

Comment: Show how you tried to use it in the question. That way we can see what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar post edited !

Comment: Typo: `$_POST['[phone'];` you have an extra `[`

Comment: Sessions are specific to a particular client. The browser session won't be transferred to webhooks that are called by Twilio.

Comment: $_POST['[phone']; i fixed this still not work

Comment: @Barmar its possible to pass variables ? or can you suggest any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use session variables between browser requests and webhook requests, since the webhook requests don't come from the same browser session.

What you should do is put the variables in the URL you pass to Twilio.

```
$url="http://example.com/2-call-answered.php?name={$_SESSION['name']}&username={$_SESSION['username']}";
```

Then `2-call-answered.php` can use `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['name']`.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
...
$gather = $response->gather(array('numDigits' => 6, 'action' => "/3-gather.php?name=$name&username=$name"));
```

Comment: i use get method it works fine but i didn't know how to pass variables to 3rd php file /3-gather.php which is file action for 2nd php file

Comment: You can add the parameters similarly to the `action` URL.